# Padding after JQuery Listview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making another JQuery Listview, but this time it will not have a slide out view. It is just simply a list of items.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/jakechasan/kNPN7/3/

However, the padding between table rows is very large. Is there a way to easily reduce this so they are right next to each other (with minimal padding). I am thinking this can be done pretty easily by overriding the default CSS for JQuery Mobile, however, I am unsure which property to override.

Here is an image of the problem:

Problem:[image]
Correct:[image]

Here is some sample code (basic code) so I am unsure where the padding comes from:

```
<ol data-role="listview">
    <li>Acura</li>
    <li>Audi</li>
    <li>BMW</li>
    <li>Cadillac</li>
    <li>Ferrari</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a number of `&nbsp;` after each closing `</li>` tag that was creating the issue.

Remove these and the extra padding dissapears.  **See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kNPN7/4/)**